# Incense and Lucky Eggs last less than 30 mins

Tags: pokemon-go

Does your incense and lucky eggs start to count down from 9 mins and 30 secs or any time duration less than 30 mins?

Whenever I use incense or lucky eggs, the timer on the side starts from 9:30 and then counts down to zero, although in the description for these items, it says that each item lasts for 30 minutes.

Comment: Can you explain your question in greater detail?

Comment: whenever i use incense or lucky egg in Pokemon Go, the timer on the side starts from 9:30 then counts down to zero. but in the description for these items, it says that each item lasts for 30 minutes. i'm not sure if anyone else is experiencing this because i tried to google this problem and i can't get any hits.

Comment: is anyone else having the same trouble as i am?

Comment: @jmends most likely your device time is incorrect

Answer (score 3):

Go to settings>time and date. Check if u have manually set the time or if it is set to "use network provided time".